# javafx tableview not loaded (is null) from fxml

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-2, fxml

i have tried to find the error since hours. i have no idea what causes this issue. i am using a controller class and a fxml. the point is, that the tableview is null in the initialize-function. no idea why.
here the controller:

```
package controller.popup;

import controller.Controllerable;
import elements.EditableTableCell;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import model.CDUSettings;
import model.Modelable;
import model.data.AnnouncementData;
import model.data.PopupData;
import model.popup.AnnouncmentsPopupModel;

public class AnnouncementsPopupController implements Controllerable, Initializable
{
// <editor-fold desc="fxml import stuff" defaultstate="collapsed">
    @FXML
    private TableView<PopupData> guiAnnouncementsTable;
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddColor"
    private TextField guiAnnouncementAddColor; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddDisplayedText"
    private TextField guiAnnouncementAddDisplayedText; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddDuration"
    private TextField guiAnnouncementAddDuration; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddFontEffect"
    private TextField guiAnnouncementAddFontEffect; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddFontSize"
    private TextField guiAnnouncementAddFontSize; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddId"
    private TextField guiAnnouncementAddId; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddType"
    private TextField guiAnnouncementAddType; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiColorColumn"
    private TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String> guiAnnouncementColorColumn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiDisplayedTextColumn"
    private TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String> guiAnnouncementDisplayedTextColumn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiDurationColumn"
    private TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String> guiAnnouncementDurationColumn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiFontEffectColumn"
    private TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String> guiAnnouncementFontEffectColumn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiFontSizeColumn"
    private TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String> guiAnnouncementFontSizeColumn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiIdColumn"
    private TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String> guiAnnouncementIdColumn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML //  fx:id="guiTypeColumn"
    private TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String> guiAnnouncementTypeColumn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
// </editor-fold>

    private Modelable model = null;

    public AnnouncementsPopupController(){
    connectToModel();
    }

    @Override
    public Modelable getModel(){
    return model;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseEvent(WindowEvent we)
    {
        CDUSettings.getInstance().clearAnnouncements();

    for(PopupData announce : model.getData()){
        CDUSettings.getInstance().addAnnouncement((AnnouncementData)announce);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        connectToModel();

        Callback<TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String> ,TableCell<AnnouncementData, String>> editableFactory = 
        new Callback<TableColumn<AnnouncementData, String>, TableCell<AnnouncementData, String>>()
    {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p){
                return new EditableTableCell();
            }
        };

        guiAnnouncementIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AnnouncementData, String>("id"));
        guiAnnouncementIdColumn.setCellFactory(editableFactory);
        guiAnnouncementIdColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String> t){
                (t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setId(t.getNewValue());  
            }
        });

        guiAnnouncementColorColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AnnouncementData, String>("color"));
        guiAnnouncementColorColumn.setCellFactory(editableFactory);
        guiAnnouncementColorColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String> t){
                (t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setColor(t.getNewValue());  
            }
        });

        guiAnnouncementDisplayedTextColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AnnouncementData, String>("displayedText"));
        guiAnnouncementDisplayedTextColumn.setCellFactory(editableFactory);
        guiAnnouncementDisplayedTextColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String> t){
                (t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setDisplayedText(t.getNewValue());  
            }
        });

        guiAnnouncementDurationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AnnouncementData, String>("duration"));
        guiAnnouncementDurationColumn.setCellFactory(editableFactory);
        guiAnnouncementDurationColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String> t){
                (t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setDuration(t.getNewValue());  
            }
        });

        guiAnnouncementFontEffectColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AnnouncementData, String>("fontEffect"));
        guiAnnouncementFontEffectColumn.setCellFactory(editableFactory);
        guiAnnouncementFontEffectColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String> t){
                (t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFontEffect(t.getNewValue());  
            }
        });

        guiAnnouncementFontSizeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AnnouncementData, String>("fontSize"));
        guiAnnouncementFontSizeColumn.setCellFactory(editableFactory);
        guiAnnouncementFontSizeColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String> t){
                (t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFontSize(t.getNewValue());  
            }
        });

        guiAnnouncementTypeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AnnouncementData, String>("type"));
        guiAnnouncementTypeColumn.setCellFactory(editableFactory);
        guiAnnouncementTypeColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AnnouncementData, String> t){
                (t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setType(t.getNewValue());  
            }
        });

        guiAnnouncementsTable.setItems(model.getData());//guiAnnouncementsTable==null at this point
    }

    public void newAddBtnEvent(ActionEvent event)
    {
        model.addDataEntry(new AnnouncementData(guiAnnouncementAddDisplayedText.getText(),
                guiAnnouncementAddId.getText(),
                guiAnnouncementAddColor.getText(),
                guiAnnouncementAddFontEffect.getText(),
                guiAnnouncementAddFontSize.getText(),
                guiAnnouncementAddType.getText(),
                guiAnnouncementAddDuration.getText()));
        guiAnnouncementAddColor.clear();
        guiAnnouncementAddDisplayedText.clear();
        guiAnnouncementAddDuration.clear();
        guiAnnouncementAddFontEffect.clear();
        guiAnnouncementAddFontSize.clear();
        guiAnnouncementAddId.clear();
        guiAnnouncementAddType.clear();

        guiAnnouncementsTable.setItems(model.getData());
    }

    private void connectToModel()
    {
    if(model == null){
        model = new AnnouncmentsPopupModel();
    }
    }
}
```

here the fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" minHeight="397.0" minWidth="264.0" prefHeight="397.0" prefWidth="819.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="controller.popup.AnnouncementsPopupController">
  <children>
    <Label text="Announcements" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="6.0">
      <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
      </font>
    </Label>
    <TableView fx:id="guiAnnouncementTable" editable="true" prefHeight="311.0" prefWidth="236.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="52.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="34.0">
      <columns>
        <TableColumn minWidth="75.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Displayed Text" fx:id="guiAnnouncementDisplayedTextColumn" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" fx:id="guiAnnouncementIdColumn" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Color" fx:id="guiAnnouncementColorColumn" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="FontEffect" fx:id="guiAnnouncementFontEffectColumn" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="FontSize" fx:id="guiAnnouncementFontSizeColumn" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Type" fx:id="guiAnnouncementTypeColumn" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Duration" fx:id="guiAnnouncementDurationColumn" />
      </columns>
    </TableView>
    <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="236.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="17.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0">
      <children>
        <TextField id="guiAnnouncementAddDisplayyedText" fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddDisplayedText" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Displayed Text" />
        <TextField fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddId" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="ID" />
        <TextField fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddColor" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="Color" />
        <TextField fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddFontEffect" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="Font Effect" />
        <TextField fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddFontSize" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="Font Size" />
        <TextField fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddType" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="Type" />
        <TextField fx:id="guiAnnouncementAddDuration" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="Duration" />
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newAddBtnEvent" text="Add" />
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

i am desperate ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you made typo in your code.
In your java file:

```
private TableView<PopupData> guiAnnouncement**s**Table;
```

there is "s" in variable name. In your fxml:

```
   <TableView fx:id="guiAnnouncementTable"
```

there is no **s**